# excluding the scatter points from a feature

Tags: python, scipy, pattern-matching, scikit-learn, pca

I have a set of data points that are supposed to sit on a locus and follow a pattern but there are some scatter points from the main locus that I would like to discard, since I need a neat locus to apply it later for my analysis. The blue points are more and less the scatter points that I want to find and exclude them via a sophisticated way without doing it manually.[image]

I was thinking of using something like `Nearest Neighbors Regression` but I am not sure whether it is the best approach or I am not very familiar how it should be implemented in order to give me an appropriate result. By the way, I want to do it without any fitting procedure. 
The transposed version of the data is a following:

```
X=array([[ 0.87 , -0.01 ,  0.575,  1.212,  0.382,  0.418, -0.01 ,  0.474,
         0.432,  0.702,  0.574,  0.45 ,  0.334,  0.565,  0.414,  0.873,
         0.381,  1.103,  0.848,  0.503,  0.27 ,  0.416,  0.939,  1.211,
         1.106,  0.321,  0.709,  0.744,  0.309,  0.247,  0.47 , -0.107,
         0.925,  1.127,  0.833,  0.963,  0.385,  0.572,  0.437,  0.577,
         0.461,  0.474,  1.046,  0.892,  0.313,  1.009,  1.048,  0.349,
         1.189,  0.302,  0.278,  0.629,  0.36 ,  1.188,  0.273,  0.191,
        -0.068,  0.95 ,  1.044,  0.776,  0.726,  1.035,  0.817,  0.55 ,
         0.387,  0.476,  0.473,  0.863,  0.252,  0.664,  0.365,  0.244,
         0.238,  1.203,  0.339,  0.528,  0.326,  0.347,  0.385,  1.139,
         0.748,  0.879,  0.324,  0.265,  0.328,  0.815,  0.38 ,  0.884,
         0.571,  0.416,  0.485,  0.683,  0.496,  0.488,  1.204,  1.18 ,
         0.465,  0.34 ,  0.335,  0.447,  0.28 ,  1.02 ,  0.519,  0.335,
         1.037,  1.126,  0.323,  0.452,  0.201,  0.321,  0.285,  0.587,
         0.292,  0.228,  0.303,  0.844,  0.229,  1.077,  0.864,  0.515,
         0.071,  0.346,  0.255,  0.88 ,  0.24 ,  0.533,  0.725,  0.339,
         0.546,  0.841,  0.43 ,  0.568,  0.311,  0.401,  0.212,  0.691,
         0.565,  0.292,  0.295,  0.587,  0.545,  0.817,  0.324,  0.456,
         0.267,  0.226,  0.262,  0.338,  1.124,  0.373,  0.814,  1.241,
         0.661,  0.229,  0.416,  1.103,  0.226,  1.168,  0.616,  0.593,
         0.803,  1.124,  0.06 ,  0.573,  0.664,  0.882,  0.286,  0.139,
         1.095,  1.112,  1.167,  0.589,  0.3  ,  0.578,  0.727,  0.252,
         0.174,  0.317,  0.427,  1.184,  0.397,  0.43 ,  0.229,  0.261,
         0.632,  0.938,  0.576,  0.37 ,  0.497,  0.54 ,  0.306,  0.315,
         0.335,  0.24 ,  0.344,  0.93 ,  0.134,  0.4  ,  0.223,  1.224,
         1.187,  1.031,  0.25 ,  0.53 , -0.147,  0.087,  0.374,  0.496,
         0.441,  0.884,  0.971,  0.749,  0.432,  0.582,  0.198,  0.615,
         1.146,  0.475,  0.595,  0.304,  0.416,  0.645,  0.281,  0.576,
         1.139,  0.316,  0.892,  0.648,  0.826,  0.299,  0.381,  0.926,
         0.606],
       [-0.154, -0.392, -0.262,  0.214, -0.403, -0.363, -0.461, -0.326,
        -0.349, -0.21 , -0.286, -0.358, -0.436, -0.297, -0.394, -0.166,
        -0.389,  0.029, -0.124, -0.335, -0.419, -0.373, -0.121,  0.358,
         0.042, -0.408, -0.189, -0.213, -0.418, -0.479, -0.303, -0.645,
        -0.153,  0.098, -0.171, -0.066, -0.368, -0.273, -0.329, -0.295,
        -0.362, -0.305, -0.052, -0.171, -0.406, -0.102,  0.011, -0.375,
         0.126, -0.411, -0.42 , -0.27 , -0.407,  0.144, -0.419, -0.465,
        -0.036, -0.099,  0.007, -0.167, -0.205, -0.011, -0.151, -0.267,
        -0.368, -0.342, -0.299, -0.143, -0.42 , -0.232, -0.368, -0.417,
        -0.432,  0.171, -0.388, -0.319, -0.407, -0.379, -0.353,  0.043,
        -0.211, -0.14 , -0.373, -0.431, -0.383, -0.142, -0.345, -0.144,
        -0.302, -0.38 , -0.337, -0.2  , -0.321, -0.269,  0.406,  0.223,
        -0.322, -0.395, -0.379, -0.324, -0.424,  0.01 , -0.298, -0.386,
         0.018,  0.157, -0.384, -0.327, -0.442, -0.388, -0.387, -0.272,
        -0.397, -0.415, -0.388, -0.106, -0.504,  0.034, -0.153, -0.32 ,
        -0.271, -0.417, -0.417, -0.136, -0.447, -0.279, -0.225, -0.372,
        -0.316, -0.161, -0.331, -0.261, -0.409, -0.338, -0.437, -0.242,
        -0.328, -0.403, -0.433, -0.274, -0.331, -0.163, -0.361, -0.298,
        -0.392, -0.447, -0.429, -0.388,  0.11 , -0.348, -0.174,  0.244,
        -0.182, -0.424, -0.319,  0.088, -0.547,  0.189, -0.216, -0.228,
        -0.17 ,  0.125, -0.073, -0.266, -0.234, -0.108, -0.395, -0.395,
         0.131,  0.074,  0.514, -0.235, -0.389, -0.288, -0.22 , -0.416,
        -0.777, -0.358, -0.31 ,  0.817, -0.363, -0.328, -0.424, -0.416,
        -0.248, -0.093, -0.28 , -0.357, -0.348, -0.298, -0.384, -0.394,
        -0.362, -0.415, -0.349, -0.08 , -0.572, -0.07 , -0.423,  0.359,
         0.4  ,  0.099, -0.426, -0.252, -0.697, -0.508, -0.348, -0.254,
        -0.307, -0.116, -0.029, -0.201, -0.302, -0.25 , -0.44 , -0.233,
         0.274, -0.295, -0.223, -0.398, -0.298, -0.209, -0.389, -0.247,
         0.225, -0.395, -0.124, -0.237, -0.104, -0.361, -0.335, -0.083,
        -0.254]])
```

Comment: a solution for this problem using R is proposed in: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/114214/55223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` to distinguish **the locus** from the scatter points. I can determine the outliers by excluding objects in **low density regions** with the criteria that their density should be less than mean_kde divided with **20**, e.g. in my case. I wrote a function that can deal with too many similar feature in different two-dimensional space and exclude all the points with similar problem from all of them at once. I also illustrated the excluded scatter points with objects with empty black circle around.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt

def refineLocus(Colorx,Colory, ratio):
    """
    Remove objects whose density is below 1/ratio of the mean density.
    The point density is estimated by Gaussian kernel convolution,
    with automatic bandwidth determination.
    Inputs: the color pair Colorx and Colory (the x- and y-color)
            the threshold ratio for the cut
    Output: object index array
    """
    for j in range(Colorx.shape[1]):
        X=np.array([[Colorx[i,j],Colory[i,j]] for i in range(Colorx.shape[0])])
        data = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=["X", "Y"])
        kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(X.T)
        kernel.set_bandwidth(bw_method='scott')
        KdeEval=np.zeros(Colorx.shape[0],float)
        for i in range(Colorx.shape[0]):
            KdeEval[i]=kernel.evaluate(X[i,:])
        ex=np.where(KdeEval<KdeEval.mean()/ratio)
        if (j==0):
           exarr=ex[0]
        else:
           if len(ex[0])!=0:
              exarr=np.unique(np.concatenate((exarr,ex[0])))
    for j in range(Colorx.shape[1]):
        X=np.array([[Colorx[i,j],Colory[i,j]] for i in range(Colorx.shape[0])])
        data = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=["X", "Y"])
        sns.kdeplot(data.X,data.Y,bw='scott',shade=True, cmap="Purples") 
        plt.scatter(Colorx[:,j],Colory[:,j],marker='.',s=2,color='red')
        plt.scatter(Colorx[exarr,j],Colory[exarr,j],s=10,facecolors='none', edgecolors='k')
        figname = 'refineLocus.kde.%d.pdf' % (j, )
        plt.savefig(figname)
        plt.close()
    return exarr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Cy=np.loadtxt('Colory.asc')
    Cx=np.loadtxt('Colorx.asc')
    arr=refineLocus(Cx,Cy, ratio=25)
    r=arange(Cx.shape[0])
    new_r=setxor1d(r,arr)
    nCX=Cx[new_r]
    nCY=Cy[new_r]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to provide the following procedure not necessarily as a perfect answer but rather as a start-up for you to upgrade it or develop something similar based on it.

What is happening? The procedure groups the points together respective to their x-values. For every group (bin) the average y-value is computed and the point with the greatest deviation which exceeds some predefined limit is discarded. Then the average value is computed again and so on. If there are no more points to be discarded the next bin is considered. You'll find comments in the code which (hopefully) give a clearer explanation.

Here's the code:

```
def discard(X):
    """
    Group points together in x-bins; discard points for every bin which deviate more than dy from the average in an iterative procedure.
    """

    dx, dy = 0.1, 0.1   # dx: bin size; dy: max. deviation

    points = sorted(zip(X[0], X[1]), key=lambda p: p[0])    # sort the points respective to x

    xx = points[0][0]   # the smallest x-value
    xmax = points[-1][0]    # the greatest x-value

    while xx < xmax:    # loop over all bins
        loop = True
        while loop:
            tmp = [p for p in points if p[0] >= xx and p[0] < xx+dx]    # all points in the current bin
            try:
                av = sum([p[1] for p in tmp]) / len(tmp)    # the average y-value
            except ZeroDivisionError:    # no points within this bin, continue with next bin
                break
            dev = sorted([p for p in tmp if abs(p[1]-av) > dy], key=lambda p: abs(p[1]-av)) # all points which deviate more than dy from the average sorted by their deviation
            try:
                points.remove(dev[-1])  # discard the point with the greatest deviation
            except IndexError:
                loop = False    # if no point is deviating more than dy continue with the next bin
        xx += dx

    return [ [p[0] for p in points], [p[1] for p in points] ]
```

Results obviously depend on the choice of `dx` and `dy`. Here are some examples (the blue points are discarded respectively). For `dx, dy = 0.1,  0.1`:

[image: for dx, dy = 0.1, 0.1]

As you can observe there are many points discarded at the right tail because the graph has a greater slope there (thus it would be better to use a greater `dy`).

For `dx, dy = 0.10, 0.15`:

[image: for dx, dy = 0.10, 0.15]

Since a greater `dy` was used less points were discarded in this case. However it is important to ensure that every bin contains enough points otherwise the procedure may fail and discard the wrong points as you can observe in the next plot, left tail (for `dx, dy = 0.09, 0.15`):

[image: for dx, dy = 0.09, 0.15]

So from what do you know which `dx, dy` to use? The best solution would probably be to keep them variable. For example:

`dx` is chosen such that in every bin there is a certain **minimum** number of points, to avoid bad discards as in the last example.
`dy` can be computed from the **slope** of the curve, i.e. the difference of the average of two neighbouring bins divided by the difference of their bin centres. Thus a greater slope leads to a greater `dy`.

This procedure is somehow similar to the *nearest neighbour algorithm* but it does for example not check every single point. Here is also space for possible modifications: instead of taking the `n` nearest neighbours you can choose `dx` such that the interval `[x-dx, x+dx]` includes `n` points and apply the above procedure.

Using the actual nearest neighbour algorithm may be problematic because you consider the deviation of a point only along the y-axis and therefore points with a x-value close to the reference's one are strongly in favour.